# How to bucket a WFFM item

Tags: wffm, buckets

I'm using the bucketing feature for the first time. The content structure is as follows:

```
|_Sitecore
  |_Content
    |_Home
      |_Products
```

*Products* is an item of *ProductFolder* template. I have made this template as bucketable. To confirm whether this is bucketed, I select *Products* and see that the Bucket icon is greyed out and the Revert & Sync icons are active.

The requirement is to add bucketable items under *Products*.

I have created another template *Product* with few fields. This template is mapped to the fields of a WFFM and configured so that, when user submits the form, an item of template *Product*, is saved under */Home/Products*.

The save functionality works fine. After saving a few items, I check the CMS and the structure is as follows:

```
|_Sitecore
  |_Content
    |_Home
      |_Products
        |_Product1
        |_Product2
```

When I click on *Product1*, *Product2*, etc., the Bucket icon is greyed out and the Revert & Sync icons are active, confirming that these are bucketed items.

But I was expecting that these items will be hidden or have a different folder structure by year/month.... Is that correct?

When I select *Products* and click on Sync, only then the child items were hidden.

In, real time, end users will submit WFFM form on page. In this case, does the content author have to periodically check and sync the folder. Or is there any way we can automate that.

Using sc 8.0 u5

Answer (score 1):

Your Product Folder must be a bucket, not bucketable, then your product template is the one that must be bucketable, in standard values.
The idea is: Bucketable means "can be added into a bucket", not "it can be converted into a bucket". You add bucketable elements into a bucket.